# How to extract only the first element from array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

```
[0
: 
"BIOCON,Biocon Ltd.,Pharma,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
1
: 
"LALPATHLAB,Dr. Lal Path Labs Ltd.,Healthcare Services,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
2
: 
"INDUSTOWER,Indus Towers Limited ,Telecom,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
3
: 
"DIVISLAB,Divi's Laboratories Ltd.,Pharma,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
4
: 
"TECHM,Tech Mahindra Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
5
: 
"IDBI,IDBI Bank Ltd.,Financial Services,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
6
: 
"ENGINERSIN,Engineers India Ltd.,Construction,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
7
: 
"KAJARIACER,Kajaria Ceramics Ltd.,Construction,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
8
: 
"SBIN,State Bank of India,Financial Services,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
9
: 
"BHARATFIN,Bharat Financial Inclusion Ltd.,Financial Services,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
10
: 
"OFSS,Oracle Financial Services Software Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
11
: 
"CENTURYTEX,Century Textile & Industries Ltd.,Cement & Cement Products,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
12
: 
"HAVELLS,Havells India Ltd.,Consumer Goods,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
13
: 
"INDIGO,InterGlobe Aviation Ltd.,Services,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
14
: 
"IPCALAB,Ipca Laboratories Limited,,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
15
: 
"ADANIPOWER,Adani Power Ltd.,Energy,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
16
: 
"GRASIM,Grasim Industries Ltd.,Cement & Cement Products,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
17
: 
"TORNTPOWER,Torrent Power Ltd.,Energy,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
18
: 
"AARTIIND,Aarti Industries Limited,Chemicals,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
19
: 
"INFIBEAM,Infibeam Incorporation Ltd.,Information Technology,2022-10-28 18:48:56"
20
: 
""]
```

Here I want only the first element from each line to map

```
 row?.split(",")?.map((splt) => (
                  console.log(splt),
                  <TCell key={splt}>{splt}</TCell>
                ))
```

Here 'row' is the array

Comment: Pass an index of `0` to the array?

Comment: Or use `shift` which Returns the first element but it also mutates the array

Comment: Um, that doesn't look like valid JavaScript _or_ React to me. Are you sure what you're posting is an array and not a mutated alien data format?

Comment: That is response data from API where I have to extract only the first element from each line

Comment: Here inside one array we have this list with unique index number, where I need first element from each index

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "first element". Include a sample of the desired output in your question, and what didn't work with your current approach.

Comment: So for first element you want `BIOCON` and the next `LALPATHLAB` and so on? And the result should be an array of those values? Making us guess what you want as an end result, really makes it hard to help.

Comment: Yes the result should be something like this: [BIOCON, LALPATHLAB, INDUSTOWER...., INFIBEAM]

Comment: Posted an answer that results in an array of `<TCell>` components. Hope that is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your output was copied from the console (it looks that way in console).

So if `row` is the array (the output) you need to, basically, do the reverse of what you've tried. You should map the array and split each iterated string, like this:

```js
row?.map(str => {
  const splt = str.split(",")[0]
  return <TCell key={splt}>{splt}</TCell>
})
```

Comment: "That is response data from API"

Comment: Yeah, and I was guessing that this response data was copied from a console.log in the browser, which makes it look the way it looks in OPs post/question.

Comment: Well, in firefox anyway. In Chrome you would have to use `console.dir` to display it with indexes in the console.